# Can another user on the same computer access my accounts if I tick "keep me signed in"?

Tags: authentication

At work on my computer I tick "keep me signed in" on nearly all the sites I visit. I left work today and I forgot to log out of all those websites.
I logged of my work account and shut it down.

If someone else logs onto that computer using their own work account, will my sites still be logged in?

Answer (score 3):

If by "work account" you mean User Account within Windows, then no. Each user account in Windows (and most other operating systems) has it's own browser data.

The remember me feature relies on the ability to store a secret token in browser data (usually Cookies), so if you switch user accounts (and browser data), then they will not have that remember me token and will therefore not be signed in on your name.

Of course, since these folks have Physical Access, they could probably break into your user account anyway, or steal the secret token. However, this requires a certain level of technical skill.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody logs on the same computer with a different account, he will have no access to your browser configuration... provided you use a normal config. I remember that we used to share configurations in the old days, but I do not think that the real risk is there.

That being said, any administrator **can** access any data on the disk. So an administrator can either access your configuration files at the file system level, or reset your password and pretend to be you. Simply he should never do that without a strong reason.

Even if you have left work definitely, an ethical admin should:

- archive your disk content without peeping into, for future reference
- wipe the disk
- and only then re-use the computer

The archive is normally destroyed after a time varying betwen a few months if you should not have important data in you disk (from the organization point of view) and a few years if there is a risk that you have left important data there.